# Gurobi optimization does not work correctly

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi

I am trying to learn to use `python3` and `Gurobi` to do some simple optimization work. I following some sample codes, however my code does not work correctly. Code attached below. Can someone point out where the mistake is? Thanks!

```
from gurobipy import *
x = np.arange(0, 10001, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 10001, 1)+1
z = np.arange(0, 10001, 1)+1

dic_sysc_1 = dict(zip(x, y))
dic_sysc_2 = dict(zip(x, z))

m = Model()
cp1 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, lb=5, ub =10000, name="cp1")
m.update()
cp2 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, lb=999, ub =10000, name="cp2")
m.update()

m.setObjective( dic_sysc_1[cp1]+dic_sysc_2[cp2], GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.setParam('OutputFlag',0)
m.optimize()

print ("Obj:", m.objVal)
print (cp1, dic_sysc_1[cp1])
print (cp2, dic_sysc_2[cp2])
```

The outputs results is:

```
Obj: 3.0
<gurobi.Var cp1 (value 5.0)> 1
<gurobi.Var cp2 (value 999.0)> 2
```

Also,then I added another constraint

```
m.addConstr( (dic_new_1[cp1]+dic_new_2[cp2]) <= 20, "c90" )
```

where `dic_new_1` and `dic_new_2` are two new dict similar to `dic_sysc_1` and `dic_sysc_2` . The model show error messages:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bool' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Is it possible that the constraints that you added does not conform with `bool` and `NoneType` ?

Answer (score 0):

That is not in the form of an integer program (MIP). You need to reformulate your model as a MIP or use another tool.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is I need to use dictionaries and decision variables to construct objective and constraints. Can you give me some hints where I can find useful information to achieve this?